# SwiftUI implement keyUp functionality

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to implement a suggestions popover functionality in SwiftUI. I have implemented it using onChange. But when the user clicks on any of the suggestions in the popover the onChange event is triggered again, which is not what I want. Ideally, I should fetch the suggestions when the user has ended typing, but I cannot find a better way to get this done.
Any help is appreciated.

```
TextField("", text: $keyword, prompt: Text("Required"))
    .onChange(of: keyword, perform: { keywordSearch in
         showsAlwaysPopover = true
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.2, execute: {
                 debouncer.run(action: {
                 self.store.fetchKeywordSuggestions(keyword: keywordSearch)
               })
         })
     })
     .alwaysPopover(isPresented: $showsAlwaysPopover) {
           if let result = self.store.keywordSuggestions {
              VStack {
                 ForEach(result, id: \.self) { i in
                    HStack {
                         Text(i)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                       keyword = i
                    }
                 }
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .padding(.all)
   }
```

Comment: Use [`.onSubmit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onsubmit(of:_:)) to fetch the suggestions.

Comment: @HunterLion .onSubmit works only when the user clicks 'enter'. I'm not looking for that. Also, even with .onSubmit the popover appears again.

Comment: yes, `.onSubmit` is called when the user clicks `enter`.
 This is how you determine when the user has ended typing,
 and that is what you say you want `...I should fetch the suggestions when the user has ended typing..`. Alternatively, you need to determine what does
 `when the user has ended typing` means for you.